# Maximum principle easy proof

Tags: maximum-principle, laplacian

Is there an easy proof of the maximum principle from the variational formulation in $\Bbb R^d$, without using Green functions?

---

Variational formulation:
$$
\forall v\, \text{ smooth, }\, \int \nabla u \cdot \nabla v = \int fv
$$
Maximum principle: if $u$ is a solution of the avriational problem, then
$$
f\ge 0 \implies u\ge 0
$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Take $v=u^{-}=\max\{-u,0\}$ in the variational formulation.

Comment: what about the problem of smoothness?

Comment: @mookid, use a density argument and Stampacchia's theorem.